# Bitcoind with ZeroMQ support

Tags: bitcoind, zeromq

I'm trying to compile from latest tag the bitcoin repo and in my use case scenario ZeroMQ support would definitely help me.

Reading the documentation I realized [this](https://github.com/wouldgo/bitcoind-docker-container) rudimental docker container. The Dockerfile installs the `libzmq3-dev` dependency and I define [these](https://github.com/wouldgo/bitcoind-docker-container/blob/master/conf/bitcoin.conf#L8) configurations in the `bitcoin.conf` file.

The result is that inside the container there isn't any bind for the defined mq enpoints and I cannot realize where the error is.

Could someone please help me to enable mq publish mechanism?

*Update*: Now the bitcoin.conf file used is [this](https://github.com/wouldgo/bitcoind-docker-container/blob/master/conf/bitcoin.conf) running in in debug it logs [this](http://pastebin.com/LMkgh4j1) debug_log.txt.

Comment: Your prune line looks weird.

Comment: @PieterWuille: probably I misunderstood the help line that describes the option. I suppose that the weirdness stands in the angle braket. Am I right?

Comment: @PieterWuille I changed the `prune` option with the 1000 value and the log report an incompatibility with the `txindex`. Removing the `prune` at all, I cannot expose the mq enpoints. Is there anything I could do trying to spot the problem?

Comment: You cannot enable both txindex and prune. Pick one.

Comment: infact I've correct removing the prune option. The fact is that there isn't any mq bound on ports specified.

Comment: Can you put your debug.log somewhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32165/discussion-between-dario-and-pieter-wuille).

Comment: @PieterWuille in the chat above I wrote down what you asked for. I'm also there. Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some investigations I realized that ZMQ support is not present on the latest tag on the repo ([this](https://github.com/wouldgo/bitcoind-docker-container/blob/c498879baecc681e0a2ecc5ee5068449782565fc/Dockerfile#L9) line was in charge of giving me the latest tag).

So I think that my problem is by now resolved by using `master` as building branch.

Thanks at all,
Dario.

Comment: Note that, latest packages from `ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin` contain ZMQ support